# Is the inverse of the Klein-Gordon equation ever used in physics?

Tags: field-theory, klein-gordon-equation, tachyon

The Klein-Gordon equation (scaling constants) is

$$\square u = -m^2 u.$$

I am wondering if the equation

$$\square u = m^2 u.$$

for real $m$ ever shows up in the physical literature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this is one equation used to study [Tachyons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tachyon) which would have a complex mass.

In the normal equation the mass term is (of course) $m^2$, but in your modified form the mass term would be $-m^2$.  The mass of a tachyon would be $im$ in your case.  One example of this is in [Revisiting Barry Cox and James Hill’s theory of superluminal motion: a possible solution to the problem of spinless tachyon localization](http://rspa.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/royprsa/471/2175/20140541.full.pdf) in section 4.

Comment: Nice, thanks. I'll wait a short time to see if anyone else posts before accepting.